# Regex for weekdays in python

Tags: python, regex

I seem to be having a problem finding the correct regex for weekdays in Python. I have tried this:

/(mon|tues|wednes|thurs|fri|satur|sun)day/

The problem is that this regex accepts if I just have "mon" in a text, but I only want it to accept if I have "monday". How do I fix this? I can't seem to understand how to do this.

Comment: That regex does *not* match "mon" not followed by "day". If your code produces output that indicates otherwise, please show your code, there might be an error elsewhere.

Comment: I see now that it was my if-statement that was wrong, thank you for making me notice! I tried to write if regex.search(sentence) print yes, but I now see that it prints yes everytime, so I will have to fix this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

this is a regular expression which works for any day of the week:

```
(Mo(n(day)?)?|Tu(e(sday)?)?|We(d(nesday)?)?|Th(u(rsday)?)?|Fr(i(day)?)?|Sa(t(urday)?)?|Su(n(day)?)?)
```

Comment: A slightly expanded version to account for cases of "Tues" or "Thur/Thurs": (Mo(n(day)?)?|Tu(e(s(day)?)?)?|We(d(nesday)?)?|Th(u(r(s(day)?)?)?)?|Fr(i(day)?)?|Sa(t(urday)?)?|Su(n(day)?)?)

Comment: @DavidMetcalfe I went just a touch further and used non-capturing groups so it's easier to find the full match. I also match single letters, except for T and S, to avoid ambiguity for Tue/Thu and Sat/Sun: https://regex101.com/r/9TWInm/1 `/((?:M(?:o(?:n(?:days?)?)?)?|(?:Tu(?:e(?:sdays?)?)?)|(?:Tues)|(?:W(?:e(?:d(?:nesdays?)?)?)?)|(?:Th(?:u(?:r(?:sdays?)?)?)?)?|(?:Thurs)|(?:F(?:r(?:i(?:days?)?)?)?)?|(?:Sa(?:t(?:urdays?)?)?)?|(?:Su(?:n(?:days?)?)?))?)(?:\W)/gm`

Answer (score 2):

Well, your regex seems to be working for me:

```
>>> import re

>>> r=re.compile(r"(mon|tues|wednes|thurs|fri|satur|sun)day")

>>> r.match("monday")
<_sre.SRE_Match at 0x2337820>

>>> r.match("mon")
```

Comment: Yeah, I see now that the problem was elsewhere. I just didn't see that it was my if-statement that was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try like below,

> a = 'your-string'
>
> result = re.findall('(mon|tues|wed|thurs|fri|sat|sun)day', a)
>
> if result:    _day = result[0] + 'day'